# How to check the element is focused to that particular field after entering hotkey in Playwright

Tags: c#, keyboard, nunit, hotkeys

**Scenario:** Hotkey for Email field is Ctrl + E

**Expected:** Focus on that email field once entered

**Script:** C#, Nunit

await Page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Control+E");

await Expect(Page.getEmailLocator()).ToBeFocusedAsync();

PressAsync does not work. Does anybody faced this solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.